# IIS Express gets stuck and css styles sometimes not being applied when debugging an ASP.NET MVC application from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-express, visual-studio-debugging

I am debugging an ASP.NET MVC app from Visual Studio 2013. When I start the debug process from Visual Studio, IIS Express where app is hosted gets stuck (my app is not started). It often happens to me. In this situation, I manually stop IIS Express from the tray icon. Even stopping IIS Express from the tray icon I often need to stop manually the debugging from Visual Studio through the stop button. Once debugging is stopped, If I try to debug again it does not work, well, sometimes works and sometimes not, it is random. I have verified that if I clear all browser history and cookies, it works in most cases except for some time. Also I have observed that Visual Studio 2013 takes a long time to boot IIS Express where my ASP.NET MVC app is hosted. Finally, I have observed that my ASP.NET MVC app hosted in IIS Express sometimes is not being displayed correctly when debugging from Visual Studio, I mean, it is displayed without css styles being applied, it seems like css styles are missed. In this case, if I stop debugging and start it again it works.

So How can I improve or solve these kind of weird issues?

Comment: “In this situation, I manually stop local IIS from the tray icon”. That's not local IIS, but IIS Express.

Comment: @LexLi Ok, I have updated my post. And do you know any kind of solution for this weird issues?

Comment: The integration between IIS Express and VS is poorly documented, so it is non-trivial to tell what's up.

Comment: Changing the port number through right-click project name then properties, sometimes helps. However, you might try hosting on Local IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IIS Express gets stuck and css styles sometimes not being applied when
>   debugging an ASP.NET MVC application from Visual Studio 2013

This is a quite strange issue and l suggest you could try these suggestions

**Suggestion**

**1)** delete all caches under `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache`, `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp` and `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`.

**2)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder,`bin`,`obj` folder under the physcial path of the solution and then reopen your project

**3)** If you have IntelliTrace, please disable `Enable IntelliTrace` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`IntelliTrace`-->`General`.

**4)** try another port like `56000` by right-clicking on the project-->`Properties`-->`Web`--> `project url`.

**5)** disable any third party extensions by `Tools`-->`Extensions and Updates` or just use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) in developer command prompt for vs2013.

**6)** try to reinstall IIS on the control panel and if your IIS is not 10.0, I suggest you could [download and use it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264).

**In addition**, VS2013 is too old and Microsoft does not continue to maintain it. So l suggest you could [download and use the latest VS2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/). It has more optimization and stronger performance than the previous VS and fixes some remaining issues from previous releases.